# Type checking Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I would like to use type checking on angular templates.

When a property has 2 or more possible types, the template is not able to determine which is the current type in its context.
Even using an "if" to check for the presence of the property, my IDE (VSCODE) isn't happy. With typescript side I could just use `if ('property' in myObj)` but I can't reproduce this on the template side.

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bjfyu9?file=src/app/app.component.html

Just remove the `FOO` interface on the property, then it work...

How can I check the type of a property in an angular template?

I read https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck but nothing about a case when a property has 2 or more types possibles (except null).

I know it could work if I add a property like "kind" for union in each object. But I can't change the data schema.

Using angular 14

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot do anything to the data schema, the last resort would be to use `any` in the template. Not anything I would ever recommend in any other situation, unless really neccessary, but if there is no other way, then do that:

```
<div *ngIf="$any(property).date">{{ $any(property).date }}</div>
```

Your forked **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bcdakp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**